# Detect if prev() item is immediately before the current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following code:

```
<p>
Suspendisse dictum <span>feugiat</span> nisl ut dapibus. <span>Mauris</span><span> iaculis porttitor</span> posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci.
</p>
```

And you use the following code:

```
$("span").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().text());
});
```

If you click on `<span> iaculis porttitor</span>`, it would alert `Mauris`. This is the correct behavior, but I only want to detect if the `prev()` element is right next to the element currently clicked. Since the previous element of `<span> iaculis porttitor</span>` is `<span>Mauris</span>`, this is working correctly.

If, however, you click on `<span>Mauris</span>`, it would alert `feugiat`, since that's the previous element's text. What I would like, is that this would return false, as there is no element directly before `<span>Mauris</span>`, only text.

Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the previousSibling is a text node

```
$("span").click(function(){
  if (this.previousSibling){
    if (this.previousSibling.nodeType == 3){
        alert(false);
    }
    else{
        alert($(this.previousSibling).text());
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/PUnce/

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. In the setting that I am trying to use this in, I have to detect if the text that is selected previous sibling is a text node or element node, but I can't seem to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/FLwxj/54/ Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: @Charlie check if the previous sibling exists before you check its node type

Comment: I understand that, but a previousSibling is existing in my fiddle, but it isn't finding the previousSibling.nodeType, and responds with `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'test.previousSibling.nodeType')` where `test` = `[
<span class="highlight">text</span>
]`

Comment: @Charlie test has to be a DOM node to use previousSibling not a jQuery object

Comment: Does the test `if (test.text() != span.text())` ever return true?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes it does. If text is highlighted, and then part of the previously highlighted text is highlighted in conjunction with new text, it will return true

Comment: @Musa How can I convert it to a DOM node? I figured `test[0]` would be sufficient, but it's not.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to get my mind round what's going on. How do you cater for a selection *overlapping* a previous selection? Should you not at some stage remove all previously inserted spans?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I've been tacking this issue for a long time, so I know what you're probably thinking. I can't remove all previously inserted spans because the text can have multiple highlighted areas, some of which are not next to each other.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. When inserting a new span you need somehow to ensure that the text of any previously inserted span is not included - right?

Comment: Correct, but I can't simply detect if the text inside is the same as part of the text in the new highlighted area, or it would end up highlighting every occurrence on the same page.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot but it looks like I got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/FLwxj/56/ Try highlighting half a word, then highlighting the other half of the word. Then try it from the other side. You'll notice the two `<span>`'s merge :)

Comment: Yes, tricky, tricky. The trouble is that a range is indiscriminate - it will encompass text regardless of markup. I think you're into custom parsing here. Raw jQuery won't help though you could phrase the custom code as a jQuery plugin if you wanted.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I know, thankfully, my scenario is very specific and easy to work with. Now I just have to see how this handles `<br>` elements... :\

Comment: I'm in Opera here - can't get anything to highlight.

Comment: Correction - just found the Highlight button

Comment: Sorry @Musa, I got carried away there, in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with jQuery. You'll have to resort to the native DOM API. Use the [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling) property on the DOM object that gets clicked. You can check whether that element is a text node or an element node by querying its [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but may have some mileage in it.

Consider two functions (both may need debugging) :

```
function unwrapUnhighlighted ($container) {
    $container.find("span.unhighlighted").unwrap();
}

function rewrapUnhighlighted ($container) {
    $container.contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            $(this).wrap('<span class="unhighlighted" />')
        }
    });
}
```

Now consider calling `unwrapUnhighlighted(...)` before inserting a new `.highlight()` span and calling `rewrapUnhighlighted (...)` afterwards.

Thus, you should be guaranteed that every text fragment is wrapped in either `<span class="highlight">...</span>` or `<span class="unhighlighted">...</span>`, and jQuery's `.prev().text()` will work as you originally expected.

For debugging, give `.unhighlighted` some background-color to make the class observable.